# Why is this is not in center?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm working with a application using Bootstrap 4. I added a button on top of a input in the right side. I'm trying to centering a "plus" icon that i can call in class with name `fa fa-plus`,
but that not works properly to center and it's a little misfit.

Below have the code that i'm using like a example.

```html
<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="edit-prospect-email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
    </div>

    <input class="form-control" id="edit-prospect-email" name="email" placeholder="Digite o email da empresa/cliente" type="email">

    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <a id="emailModal_id" class="btn btn-outline-info open-email-modal" title="Adicionar Outros email">
        <div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button works like this. As shown in the picture.

[image: button]

The "plus" icon it's a litte misfit, it's not completely in the center.

I've already tried other things like change it:

```
<div class="text-center"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></div>
```

To it:

```
<div class="text-center" ><b style="font-size:18px">+</b></div>
```

When i put manually the "+", works well. But the size is small. When i use the `class="fas fa-plus"`, Not works well.

Have a possible alternative to fix it?

Comment: Works for me https://www.bootply.com/S6qHkyeALL

Comment: `text-center` centers horizontally. You probably have something affecting `line-height` and/or `font-size` of that element.

Comment: It's different like show with me. I don't put the all things because have a lot of php conditions in Laravel. But i will try to works it in bootply. @j08691.

Comment: @j08691 i can't save, but if i put <i style="font-size:8px" class="fa fa-plus"></i> can show the plus sign out of axis.

Comment: @HereticMonkey when i reduce the size of "plus". it's out of axis too. When i increase the size it's only a illusion that seems that is not out of axis. But it's not what i want.

Comment: Right, you appear to be use Font Awesome's icon font. Since it's a font, things like `font-size` and `line-height` determine the position of the glyph on the line. If you don't use the sizes provided by Font Awesome, then you're on your own to find the right combination of CSS properties to make it appear correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some issues in padding so I removed it and center + icon. I also removed `text-center` class from your code

```css
#emailModal_id {
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.10.2/css/all.css">

<div class="form-group mb-3">
  <label class="form-control-label" for="edit-prospect-email">{{ __('Email') }}</label>
  <div class="input-group input-group-alternative">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text"><i class="ni ni-email-83"></i></span>
    </div>

    <input class="form-control" id="edit-prospect-email" name="email" placeholder="Digite o email da empresa/cliente" type="email">

    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <a id="emailModal_id" class="btn btn-outline-info open-email-modal" title="Adicionar Outros email">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`text-align` wouldn't help that much here, since the plus text is not directly inside the markup (Font Awesome uses pseudo elements with `content: '+'`). In this particular case, `position: relative` on the icon's parent and `position: absolute` on the icon itself, plus adjusting the **heights** and **top**/**left** positions can do it reliably.

Comment: Not works properly, but you give me a idea. I change the class to put de "+" content.